# How to create JSON using Plain Old Javascript Object

Tags: javascript

How to create JSON using Plain Old Javascript Object.Create pojo class for each element in the list using javascript.

Comment: This question doesn't appear to make any sense; can you clarify your intent, and requirements? Post any relevant code you might have?

Answer (score 0):

JSON is really just a normal JavaScript object (hence the name JavaScript Object Notation), it just has a more strictly specified format, and some other limitations (e.g. no funtions).

To convert an object to *JSON string*, you can use the `#stringify()` function:

```
var obj {
    "can_has": "cheeseburger"
};
JSON.stringify(obj);
```